# C# Api VkNet Не подключается

Tags: c#, api, vknet

```
Install-Package : Не удалось найти версию «NLog», совместимую с 'VkNet 1.32.0 ограничение: NLog (>= 4.5.0-rc05)'.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Install-Package VkNet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Вот такое выбивает при попытке подключить к проекту. Ничего не нашел в интернете! Что делать?

Comment: Плохо искали... [Официальный GitHub](https://github.com/vknet/vk), смотрим жирный шрифт: **Для обновления на версию 1.30.2 или выше необходимо сначала установить предварительную версию NLog 4.5.0-rc05 или выше**

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Промахнулись мимо поля "ответ" )

Comment: @AK Думаете это годится на полноценный ответ?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если ваша рекомендация решает вопрос, то подходит!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Для меня ответ, это развёрнутое пояснение того, что нужно сделать для решения проблемы. Здесь я такое написать не могу, но перенёс комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На их [GitHub](https://github.com/vknet/vk) можно увидеть данную надпись:

> Для обновления на версию **1.30.2 или выше** необходимо **сначала** установить предварительную версию NLog 4.5.0-rc05 или выше.

То есть перед установкой последней версии, вам надо руками установить пакет **NLog 4.5.0-rc05 или выше**.